# Display media files only to the user who uploaded them

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, iframe

I need to display on my website media files. For pictures no problem, but for .mht I use iframe and for docx,xlsx,pdf I use google viewer.
The display occurs in a session protected page.
The files are in a folder protected with htaccess:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

By doing this way the iframe and the google viewer fails to access the files as they aren't authorized.

One solution I was thinking would be to detect user ip and add following rules to the htaccess:

```
allow from google.com
allow from 'user_ip'
```

But anyone with a google compute engine account could sneak in.

I could use rewrite engine:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^myfiles/([^/]*)^.pdf$ /index.php?file=$1& [L]
 Options All -Indexes
```

And check the user session in index.php, but my iframe and the google viewer are added dynamically through Ajax calls...

I could also make a temporary copy of the file to a publicly accessible folder. But anyone could just snif this folder and after a while get the whole collection of the files viewed through this.

Any idea on how to restrict access to these files to the users with a valid session only launching an iframe or a google viewer ?

Comment: Validate with user-agent?  Bad idea anywa, a MITM  attack will get that as well. Perhaps you should state your purpose, that might be better way to perform the task.

Comment: the purpose is to display media files only to the user who uploaded them. As I got diverse types of files I have to use iframe or google viewer to render them.

Comment: Then I suggest you change the title to suite your task, so people with the same experience can share the knowledge, otherwise the misleading title will drive them away.